# How to insert data into SQL Server database to a datagridview using vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I want to retrieve data from a SQL Server 2012 database into a datagridview in vb. I created a connection class for connecting an each an every form to the db. I also created a method call `getData` to execute the SQL statement and fill the data for dataset. This is my code for the data `GetData` button

```
Private Sub btnGetData_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnGetData.Click
    Dim tmpDS As DataSet

    Try

        For rowIndex As Integer = 0 To DataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1

            Dim objcon As New clsCon
            objcon.GetData("SELECT * FROM StockMF")

            If objcon.DS.Tables(0).Rows.Count > 0 Then
                tmpDS = objcon.DS

                DataGridView1.Rows(0).Cells(0).Value = tmpDS.Tables(0).Rows(0).Item("StockId")
                DataGridView1.Rows(0).Cells(1).Value = tmpDS.Tables(0).Rows(0).Item("ItemNo")
                DataGridView1.Rows(0).Cells(2).Value = tmpDS.Tables(0).Rows(0).Item("ItemNm")
                DataGridView1.Rows(0).Cells(3).Value = tmpDS.Tables(0).Rows(0).Item("UnitPrice")
                DataGridView1.Rows(0).Cells(4).Value = tmpDS.Tables(0).Rows(0).Item("AvailQty")

            End If
           Next rowIndex

    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try

End Sub
```

But I only get one record from the database. How to correct this code retrieve all the records recorded in the database? I also need to know how to clear the datagridview

Comment: You need to start with this [DataGridView.DataSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.datasource(v=vs.110).aspx). Read the examples

Answer (score 0):

to fill the datagridview, do this

```
Try
   Dim objcon As New clsCon
   Dim dt As New DataTable
   dt = objcon.GetData("SELECT * FROM StockMF")
   DataGridView1.DataSource = dt  
Catch ex As Exception
   MsgBox(ex.Message)
End Try
```

to remove all data from the datagridview,

```
DataGridView1.DataSource = Nothing
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.I try this code,but it didn't worked.data not seems to be appear.

Comment: does `objcon.GetData()` return a datatable? I'm not really sure about your `clsCon` class. I have updated the answer, if it is still wrong please do edit your question and add the `clsCon` class ;)

Comment: This work fine for me.Thanks for helping me out to build my solution

Comment: DataGridView1.DataSource = dt  You missing data bind.

    DataGridView1.DataBind()